# How to bind a Paginate button OnClick event in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, pagination

I'm using a `Datatable` to populate a large number of records in my web-site project. And due to the big number of data I don't want to load all the records, thus obviously I need to do it in a pagination manner.

So, in my `Datatable` I want each page to display only 10 records, and then when the user clicks on paginate button "2,3,...." or when click on "Next" I want then to bind the click event to get the clicked page number and based on that display the next batch of records.

I have this `query` which I will use in the `SQL Server` side to fetch the corresponding data:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY INSERTED_TIMESTAMP OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

I want the `offset` value to be changed as per the requested page number. The idea that crossed my mind is to get the clicked paginate `button` number and then multiply it by 10.

So my question is how to do that and if if you have any other suggestions to approach that please suggest me

Comment: Did u got the answers?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approach to do this task.

1. Let you UI hold a key that keeps track of the current page being fetched. So say initially this value is 0. When you click on next button, increment this value by 1 and multiply it will page size(10 in your case). This gives you you offset and start position.
2. With each response from your backend, send a key that gives the next offset. So say that you send the request 1st time, the response returns a key with offset 11. Next time use this to get the next set of records.

Hope this is helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Server Side Pagination` feature of `datatables`. A complete documentation is available here.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

The basic idea in above link is when you click a `page number` or `next button` `server side` call is made through `ajax`. In that call you get the `page number` or `start` and `end`. You can use these numbers to get data from database and send back to `datatable`.

Comment: yeah dear I already went through this documentation but I'm still not managing how to pass the page number into the ajax call, any ideas please?

Comment: Which language are you using ?